# How can I get request per second during the locust test execution?

Tags: performance-testing, locust

I want to log requests per second before and after the user thread execution. How can I use any of locust api to log get the information from locust execution context.

Basically what we get in the locust graph report while executing the locust test.

Answer (score 1):

You can access [RequestStats](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/_modules/locust/stats.html#RequestStats) using `self.environment.stats` inside a running task/User.

For example, you can terminate a test early by doing the following in a task (or in a separate greenlet)

```
if self.environment.stats.total.total_rps > 10:
    self.environment.runner.quit()
```